# Netlify form submission blank with react-final-form plugin

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, react-final-form

I am using react-final-form to develop a multi-page wizard form but am now stuck on sending my submissions to Netlify.

Netlify has detected my form but on submit doesn't receive my forms data
[image]

This is my first time using Netlify to handle form submissions so I'm not sure if I'm doing something
wrong on Netlifys side or react-final-forms side.

*****important***
im using GATSBY**

index.js

```
<Wizard onSubmit={onSubmit}>
<Wizard.Page>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label css={label}>> Name</label>
        </div>
        <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            css={input}
            name="Name"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="$"
            validate={required}
        />
        <Error name="Name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label css={label}>> Email</label>
        </div>
        <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            css={input}
            name="Email"
            component="input"
            type="email"
            placeholder="$"
            validate={required}
        />
        <Error name="Email" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <label css={label}>> Social handle</label>
        </div>
        <Field
            autocomplete="off"
            css={input}
            name="Social"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="$"
        />
        <Error name="Social" />
    </div>
</Wizard.Page>

<Wizard.Page>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label css={label}>> What can we do for you?</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    paddingTop: '0.5em',
                }}
            >
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="Shopify build"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>Shopify build</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="pop-up store"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>Pop-up store</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="WebVR"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>WebVR</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="Website audit"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>Website audit</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="Asset creation"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>Asset creation</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Field
                    css={checkbox}
                    onClick={play}
                    name="services"
                    component="input"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="Other"
                />{' '}
                <span css={checkboxlabel}>Other</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div style={{ paddingTop: '1em' }}>
            <label css={label}>> Budget</label>
        </div>
        <Field css={budget} name="Budget" component="select">
            <option />
            <option value="UNDER > $3000">UNDER > $3000</option>
            <option value="$3000 - $10000">$3000 - $10000</option>
            <option value="$10000 - $15000">$10000 - $15000</option>
            <option value="$15000 - $25000">$15000 - $25000</option>
            <option value="$25000+">$25000+</option>
        </Field>
        <Error name="budget" />
    </div>
</Wizard.Page>
<Wizard.Page>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label css={label}>> Message</label>
        </div>
        <Field
            css={message}
            name="message"
            component="textarea"
            placeholder="$"
        />
        <Error name="message" />
    </div>
</Wizard.Page>
```

Wizard.js

```
    handleSubmit = values => {
    const { children, onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1
    if (isLastPage) {
        return onSubmit(values)
    } else {
        this.next(values)
    }
}



render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { page, values } = this.state
    const activePage = React.Children.toArray(children)[page]
    const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1
    
    return (
        <Form
            autocomplete="off"
            initialValues={values}
            validate={this.validate}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  
        >
            {({ handleSubmit, submitting, values }) => (
                <form name="notypo-services" method="POST" data-netlify="true" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {activePage}
                    <div className="buttons">
                        {page > 0 && (
                            <div onClick={this.previous}>
                                <PrevButton></PrevButton>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {!isLastPage && (
                            <NextButton></NextButton>   
                        )}
                        {isLastPage && (
                            <div type="submit">
                                <SendButton></SendButton>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </form>
            )}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` tag should have an `action` and the data provided should have a `key`-`value` pair:

```
<form name="notypo-services" 
      method="POST" 
      data-netlify="true" 
      action="/"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

And your data should be structured like:

```
form-name: "notypo-services"
Name: "Your typed name"
Email: "Your typed email"
```

Note the `form-name` value. It's mandatory.

If you don't have a `thank-you` page, you can redirect the action to himself by `/`.

In addition, I would suggest adding [`data-netlify-honeypot`](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/spam-filters/#honeypot-field) to avoid spam.

You can check the [Netlify documentation](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/) for further details.

Comment: Hey! added  action="/" but it didn't send me to the thank you page

and my data is structured like this:

Budget: "UNDER > $3000"
Email: "mitch@gmail.com"
Name: "mitch"
Social: "mitch313123"
message: "this is a test submit for stack overflow"
services: ["Asset creation"]

based on my console.log(values)

Comment: also still no data received on Netlifys side

Comment: There's no `form-name` field according to what you said

Comment: Ok, so a bit of a problem.

<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="notypo-services" />
does not get detected in the values.

So I tried -

<Field  component="input" type="hidden" name="form-name" value="notypo-services"                       />

But according to the react-final-form docs you can’t add values to input fields (only checkboxes & radios)
https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#value

due to this, I think Netlify and react-final-form might not be compatible, well at least with the way I've set it up.

Comment: You can always manipulate you data object before sending it to add your form name value.

Answer (score 0):

after days of procrastinating, I finally put this together

On submit I transfer my data into a hidden form that then gets sent over to Netlify (succesfully)

```
handleSubmit = values => {
    const { children, onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    const isLastPage = page === React.Children.count(children) - 1
    if (isLastPage) {
        document.getElementById("realFormName").value = "notypo-services";
        document.getElementById("realName").value = values.Name ;
        document.getElementById("realEmail").value =  values.Email;
        document.getElementById("realSocial").value =  values.Social;
        document.getElementById("realServices").value =  values.Services;
        document.getElementById("realBudget").value =  values.Budget;
        document.getElementById("realMessage").value =  values.Message;
        
        
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit() ;

        return false ;
    } else {
        this.next(values)
    }
}

<form id="myForm" name="notypo-services" method="POST" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" action="/" style={{display: 'none'}}>
     <input hidden="true" name="form-name" type="text" id="realFormName" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Name" type="text" id="realName" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Email" type="email" id="realEmail" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Social" type="text" id="realSocial" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Services" type="text" id="realServices" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Budget" type="text" id="realBudget" />
     <input hidden="true" name="Message" type="text" id="realMessage" />
            
     <input hidden="true" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: is this the index.html file in your public folder?